# generate random numbers between two limits in solr

Tags: solr, solrcloud, solr6

We have a requirement to add a random number to a field and sort it .

eg; we have rank which is integer in each document. we need to add some random number between 1-10 to rank field in each document and finally sort it in ascending.

by doing this we can rearrange the product each time we call in the solr response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this using the combination of sum and scale. Using the scale function i was able to scale the random_ to min and max values in my case 0 to 10.

then use the sum function to add that value to the integer field.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possibility to achieve this is to have [RandomSortField](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/8_2_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/schema/RandomSortField.html), which could be used as a second field for sorting.

schema.xml:

```
<fieldType name="random" class="solr.RandomSortField" />
<dynamicField name="random*" type="random" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
```

then, you would need to do sorting during query time like this:

```
sort=rank DESC,random_1 DESC
```

So, you will be able to achieve what you want, the only caveat is, that values of `RandomSortField` wouldn't be from 1 to 10, but rather truly random.

Comment: Note that this will not work with SolrCloud as the random value will differ across instances.